Orthonormal basis for a $L^2(I_1 \cup I_2)$.
We know that $\{e^{2 \pi i n t}\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is an orthonormal basis for $L^2[0, 1]$. Suppose I have a union of two disjoint intervals $I_1 \cup I_2$. Consider $L^2(I_1 \cup I_2)$, does this necessarily have an exponential orthonormal basis as above? Keep in mind, I do not mean we necessarily take the same set, but something of the form $\{e^{2 \pi i \alpha_n t}\}_{\alpha_n \in A}$. Can this be done? If not what are the known results, specifically for orthonormal basis?

WLOG we may assume that $|I_1|+|I_2|=1.$ There is the trivial example where the set $\{e^{2\pi int}\}$ is the orthonormal basis, namely
$I_1=[0,a]$ and $I_2=[a+k,k]$ for $k\in \mathbb{N}.$ However for $I_1=[0,1/2]$ and $I_2=[2/3,4/3]$ no orthogonal basis of the form $\{e^{ 6i\beta_nt}\}$ (for convenience $\beta_n=\pi \alpha_n/3)$ exists.
Assume $b$ satisfies $$ \int\limits_0^{1/2 }e^{6ibt}\,dt+\int\limits_{2/3}^{4/3} e^{6ibt}\,dt=0$$
Then for $z=e^{ib}$ we get
$$z^8-z^4+z^3-1=0\ (*)$$ According to Wolframalpha the number $1$ is the only root of the equation with absolute value $1.$ Let $\{e^{ 6i\beta_nt}\}$ constitute an orthogonal set. For $n\neq  m$ we get
$$\int\limits_{I_1\cup I_2}e^{6i\beta_nt} e^{-6i\beta_mt}\,dt=0\ (**)$$ which implies that   $z=e^{6i(\beta_n-\beta_m)}$ satisfies $(*).$ Therefore $e^{6i(\beta_n-\beta_m)}=1,$ which leads to a contradiction with $(**).$
